# Simple SQL query throws error

Tags: sql

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL
>   Server error '80040e14'
>
> The column prefix 'tblUsers' does not
>   match with a table name or alias name
>   used in the query

The query being executed is:

```
SELECT tblProjects.projectName, tblUsers.username
FROM tblProjects
INNER JOIN
    tblUsers ON tblProjects.userID = tblUsers.ID
WHERE (tblProjects.ID = 190)
```

When I run this in SQL Server 2005 though, it runs fine and returns the correct result!  In my code, this throws the error.

It is being invoked through a classic ASP script:

```
strSQL = "SELECT tblProjects.projectName, tblUsers.username FROM tblProjects INNER JOIN tblUsers ON tblProjects.userID = tblUsers.ID WHERE (tblProjects.ID = " & lngProjectID & ")" 
rsCommon.open strSQL, adoCon
    strProjectPath = "../projects/" & rsCommon("username") & "/" & rsCommon("projectName")
rsCommon.close
```

Comment: @Tom - Can you post your code on how you are invoking this query to execute?

Comment: It does sound like its your connection / method of executing the query that is at fault here.

Comment: Hi everyone, I'm a complete idiot.  Thanks for looking though.  Error is a different line.  It's late, it's monday I'm tired :S  Sorry!

Comment: Oh god now I feel really bad because people have put in proper answers, so sorry everyone :-(

Comment: i think the problem here is your hungarian notation. ;)

Comment: @Tom - Saw your comment. Anyway you did get the error right? You can post your fix as answer and mark it as correct answer tough.

Comment: There was nothing wrong with the query, it was a statement on a different line throwing the error which was just a basic syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I do not see any reason why this would throw error. Query and the code seems fine. Can the problem be somewhere else? You can try adding brackets as suggested by @Micheal. Hope that works.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, I would try putting all table and column names in square brackets and see if the problem gets resolved:

```
SELECT [tblProjects].[projectName], [tblUsers].[username] 
FROM [tblProjects] 
INNER JOIN 
    [tblUsers] ON [tblProjects].[userID] = [tblUsers].[ID] 
WHERE [tblProjects].[ID] = 190
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but is it POSSIBLE????  that the Ole DB provider is falsely choking on "INNER JOIN" instead of a simple "JOIN" and the token parsing by the engine is missing the alias tblUsers?

Answer (score 1):

Try to prefix the table names with the schema.
I.E.

```
SELECT [dbo].[tblProjects].[projectName], [dbo].[tblUsers].[username]
FROM [dbo].[tblProjects]
INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[tblUsers] ON [dbo].[tblProjects].[userID] = [dbo].[tblUsers].[ID]
WHERE ([dbo].[tblProjects].[ID] = 190)
```

if you use a schema other than `dbo`, specify it.
When you just run a query, maybe there is a default schema selected, unlike the case when you connect via a simple connection string and try to run this query.